# South ignores ManyToManyField in my model

Tags: django, migration, many-to-many, django-south

My model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(AuditGroup)
    topic   = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The migration created:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'Article'
        db.create_table('certification_article', (
            ('id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('user', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['auth.User'])),
            ('title', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255)),
            ('short_desc', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TextField')(blank=True)),
        ))
```

None of the two many-to-many relationships are being produced! What am I missing?

Note: there's a strange thing in my model (took over the project): There is a class ProgramOverview in my model.py. But all code in this class is lowercase! In fact running --auto on schemamigration produces errors about ProgramOverview. Removing it, south wants to delete this class (turns out this is a view in the DB which is needed!) --> This seems to have been put there for some "hacky-ish" reason...So I produced the migration with:

```
./manage.py schemamigration certification --add-model Article
```

EDIT: **This** is the real problem. Somehow my editor messed up the ProgramOverview code. After restoring the code, I was able to run ./manage.py schemamigration certification --auto which produced all the needed tables!
END EDIT

I need the many-to-many though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't see an M2M in that declaration. What you see is *correct*.

An M2M "field" is an abstraction for a new table. There is no database level field in the 'Article' model.

Scan down the page to see the relevant M2M table creation code.

Comment: I see, understood, I can see further down: 'certification.article': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'Article'},
            'categories': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': "orm['certification.AuditGroup']", 'symmetrical': 'False'}),

but when I execute the code to save a new object with those relationships, I get 
relation "certification_article_categories" does not exist
 This is indeed strange, isnt't? Is that because of the --add-model flag? Why is the migration not creating the relationship tables?

Comment: Never mind. The key for my specific problem is in my Note: in the question commit. This was not there for a hacky-ish reason, but because I must have been doing something wrong with my editor. I picked up the original ProgramOverview code, pasted it back into my editing models.py, and executed `./manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto` - worked fine this time, and tables created correctly.